# I am getting the same result for every row

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

this is probably a basic sql challenge that I'm experiencing.

I have a query where I want to grab each of the company IDs from a table and then the date that each company was created and the number of days between the creation date and today.

I put together this query --

```
SELECT 
company_id,
DATE(datecreated),
datediff(day,datecreated, current_date)
FROM companies
```

But I get results that look like this --

```
companyid   datecreated datediff
abc         1/4/15      753
cba         1/4/15      753
bbb         1/4/15      753
aaa         1/4/15      753
```

It seems to be selecting just one of the company IDs and filling in date() and datediff() for that companyid into all the rows below it.

I tried grouping them, but that didn't work. Same result.

This is what my data looks like --

```
companyid   datecreated
abc         1/4/15
cba         1/9/16
bbb         1/3/17
aaa         1/5/17
```

Do you know why this might be happening? Thanks.

Comment: "a postgres mysql db". PostgreSQL and MySQL are two completely different database engines. Which one are you using?

Comment: None of the databases you mention support `datediff()` as you have used it.  Please tag the question correctly.

Comment: i'm using a redshift database. I assumed that it uses mysql but it sounds like I was mistaken.

Comment: here's the redshift doc on datediff(). How would you recommend I use it? http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_DATEDIFF_function.html

Comment: "I assumed that it uses mysql"... but http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_redshift-and-postgres-sql.html clearly says "Amazon Redshift is based on PostgreSQL 8.0.2. Amazon Redshift and PostgreSQL have a number of very important differences that you must be aware of as you design and develop your data warehouse applications.". No mention of MySQL.

Comment: Thank you, that's really helpful

Answer (score 0):

Works perfectly for me. 
 
[image]

If I’ve made a bad assumption please comment and I’ll refocus my answer.